# Get lines with maximum value in each group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a user table that look like this :

| id | dtCreation | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | aaa |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | aaa |
| 3 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | bbb |
| 4 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | bbb |
| 5 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | ccc |
| 6 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | ccc |

And I'm trying to get the last created user (by dtCreation) for each type.
So far I select everything with group done on the type and selecting the line with the highest creation date in each group with the `HAVING` clause.

My request is :

```sql
  SELECT u.id, u.dtCreation, u.type FROM users u 
   WHERE u.type IN ('aaa','bbb','ccc')
GROUP BY u.type 
  HAVING MAX(u.dtCreation) = u.dtCreation;
```

But I don't get any result from this request, is there something that I'm missing ?

Comment: How do you define *last*? By id, by dtCreation, or by the combination of both?

Comment: Only by dtCreation

Comment: Does your query even run? Can you share a fiddle

Comment: They are the same some are from 2021 and other from 2022 (that not the real dataset but in the real one the dates are not the sames either)

Comment: Try this 

`SELECT id
FROM
tablename
INNER JOIN(SELECT MAX(a.dt_creation), a.type FROM tablename a GROUP BY a.type) a
ON tablename.id = a.id`